# Rails 4 has_many through association, unsure why the association is failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through

**Here are my models:**

```
class Pizza < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pizza_type
  has_many :toppings, through: :pizza_toppings
end

class Topping < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :topping_type
  has_many :pizza_size_topping_prices
  has_many :pizzas, through: :pizza_toppings
end

class PizzaTopping < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pizza
  belongs_to :topping
end
```

**DB Schema**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140108194303) do

  create_table "pizza_size_topping_prices", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "pizza_size_id"
    t.integer  "topping_id"
    t.float    "half_price"
    t.float    "whole_price"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "pizza_sizes", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "pizza_toppings", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "pizza_id"
    t.integer  "topping_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "pizza_type_size_prices", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "pizza_size_id"
    t.integer  "pizza_type_id"
    t.float    "base_price"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "pizza_types", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "description"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "pizzas", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "pizza_type_id"
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "description"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "topping_types", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "toppings", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "topping_type_id"
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "description"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

end
```

**When I attempt to find the toppings for the pizza via white_pizza.toppings, I get the error:**

```
 ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the association :pizza_toppings in model Pizza
```

**Here's the IRB console:**

```
Loading development environment (Rails 4.0.0)
irb(main):001:0> white_pizza = Pizza.last
  Pizza Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "pizzas".* FROM "pizzas" ORDER BY "pizzas"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
=> #<Pizza id: 3, pizza_type_id: 5, name: "first white pizza", description: "first white pizza description", created_at: "2014-01-08 20:20:25", updated_at: "2014-01-08 20:20:25">
irb(main):002:0> white_pizza.toppings
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the association :pizza_toppings in model Pizza
    from /home/gcardella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:550:in `check_validity!'
    from /home/gcardella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:25:in `initialize'
    from /home/gcardella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_through_association.rb:9:in `initialize'
    from /home/gcardella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/associations.rb:157:in `new'
    from /home/gcardella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/associations.rb:157:in `association'
    from /home/gcardella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:70:in `toppings'
    from (irb):2
    from /home/gcardella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /home/gcardella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /home/gcardella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:64:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Anyone know why this is happening? I thought that based on this relationship, I could get the many toppings for the pizza this way. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both your `Pizza` and `Topping` classes need the following line, otherwise the `has_many :through` part won't work correctly:

```
has_many :pizza_toppings
```